# Get Current Path of IIS Hosted AppFabric Workflow Service

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, appfabric, workflowservice

In an IIS hosted workflow service, how do I get the current path of the workflow?

For example, my workflow is deployed in the following directory:

```
/Site/WebApp/SubDir/MyWorkflowService.xamlx
```

If the IIS application is created on /Site/WebApp (and the web.config is in this directory), how do I get the path /Site/WebApp/SubDir from inside a CodeActivity or NativeActivity?

I figured out how to get the path of the IIS application by using System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment, but I am unable to find a way to find the path of the current workflow if it is deployed in a sub-directory of an IIS applcation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to do determine the path at startup time in an IServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior() and use a workflow extension to provide it to your workflow activities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very helpful hint. Did you mean IServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior()?

Comment: Just to provide more details, to get the paths, I casted the ServiceHostBase to a WorkflowServiceHost, then grabbed the VirtualPathExtension, which contains all the path information: `var workflowServiceHost = (WorkflowServiceHost)serviceHostBase;
var virtualPathExtension = workflowServiceHost.Extensions.Find<VirtualPathExtension>();`